# Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, collections, model, path

I've two models say **"Page"** and **"Product"** Product's PageID refers to Page's ID

and in my Product Index View, I need to get the Page list as a drop-down, for that I'm using

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
   var products = _db.Products.Include(p => p.Page);
            return View(products.ToList());
}
```

But what I need is only those pages whose **PageGroup** property has a value *'Product'*. for that I used

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var products = _db.Products.Include(p => p.Page.PageGroup
                                   .Contains(PageGroup.Product.ToString()));
    return View(products.ToList());
}
```

It's giving an error as follows:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties. Parameter name: path

Answer (score 3):

instead of

`var products = _db.Products.Include(p => p.Page.PageGroup.Contains(PageGroup.Product.ToString()));`

you want something like this.

`var products = _db.Products.Include(p => p.Page).Where(p => p.Page.PageGroup.Contains(PageGroup.Product.ToString());`

You may have to include some more sub properties (like PageGroup) to check your actual condition, but I can't say for sure without knowing more about your data model.