# LINQ Include error

Tags: c#, database, linq, linq-to-entities

I am new to using asp .net and LINQ queries. I wrote the following query but am getting an error.

[Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854033/include-path-expression-must-refer-to-a-navigation-property-defined-on-the-type)

In the above question there is the same error but they don't explain why it is happening at all. I believe it is because I included the inline .First() method on the third line below but again I want to know why this occurs and what it means. Thank you for your help.

Error:

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the
type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select
operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path
```

Query:

```
IQueryable<User> users = db.Users
    .Where(u => u.Email == email)
    .Include(cu => cu.CompanyUsers.First())
    .Include(c => c.Companies)
    .Include(p => p.ParentCompanyAccounts );
```

Comment: Can you show the definition  of the `User`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I am getting the other queries back before but the problem was a user can be in multiple Companies so before i was getting back multiple results so thats why I put first on there. Ill post the important parts of the model. Thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the 3rd line of your query. When you are including something using the `Include` method, you can't just take one of an object. You have to take them all.

So where you have:

`.Include(cu => cu.CompanyUsers.First())`

Should be:

`.Include(cu => cu.CompanyUsers);`

For a good look at how to use `Include`, I recommend taking a look at [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `First` in an `Include` call.  If you're going to use `Include`, you need to include *all* of the related values.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the call to just one or do I have to do that after the query has executed?

Comment: @Ellery There's no way to filter the set using `Include`, no.

Comment: @Ellery The whole point of using `Include` is that you want all of something to be loaded into memory right away. Otherwise, you're looking for something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can user a transient property along with a persistent property.

```
class User
{
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<User> CompanyUsers {get; set;} //persistent property

    [NotMapped]
    public User FirstCompanyUser   //transient property
    {
         get{ return CompanyUsers.FirstOrDefault(); }
    }
}
```

You can user a partial class to avoid code loss on regeneration if you use data first approach.